# Javascript function returns previous value or undefined

Tags: javascript, function, return

Learning javascript for the 5th time, basic coding background and foreigner (not a native English speaker, so could not find the proper answer).

I have a basic function which I want to return the a value typed by a user:

```
var number = ' ';
function askNumber(){
    number = parseInt(prompt('Type a number :'));
    if (isNaN(number)){
        askNumber();

    }else{
        return number;
    }
}

console.log(askNumber());
```

When you first type characters, it will call the function again.
If the second time you type some numbers, then the function will return 'undefined'.

--

Now, if I add if/else to call the function when the number is higher than 999 and lower than 0, then if I type a higher number, and then a correct number, the higher number is returned.

It seems the return statement does not return the correct value once the function is called again... recursively?

How to make sure the

> return number;

returns the last value typed by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not mean to. You are calling the function but not returning the value

```js
var number = ' ';
function askNumber(){
    number = parseInt(prompt('Type a number :'));
    if (isNaN(number)){
        // Notice the return statement:
        return askNumber();
    } else {
        return number;
    }
    /*
    You could change the above if...else to:
    return isNaN(number) ? askNumber() : number;
    */
}
console.log(askNumber());
```

**ADDRESSING COMMENT**:

```js
function addOne(n) {
  return n + 1;
  // No matter what n is, it returns n + 1;
}
function addTwo(n) {
  let newN = addOne(n); // the return value of addOne comes HERE.
  let newNewN = addOne(newN) // Again, the return value comes here.
  return newNewN;
}
console.log(addTwo(1));
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer.
Would you care to elaborate?
The way I understand this:
I get in the function, I type characters instead of numbers, so the functions calls itself.
But then I type numbers, and the if condition is not fullfilled, so it goes directly to 'return number'.
Why would I need to return the function : return askNumber(); ? It calls it, but why returning it?

Thanks

Comment: I used to think what you think now. But: When you call the askNumber function, the return value is not returned to the original askNumber call. Instead, it comes back to the if block, to the askNumber() line. See (future?) edit.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `return` statement.

```
var number = ' ';
function askNumber2(){
    number = parseInt(prompt('Type a number :'));
    if (isNaN(number)){
        return askNumber();
    } else {
        return number;
    }
}
```